# position=dodge in geom_col in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is a dataset of soccer players that I need to visualise the total number of yellow cards received next to the number of games played per country in one bar plot. SO I need to calculate the total number of yellow cards and the total number of games per league country and bring the data into long format.

```
    dput(head(new_soccer_referee))
structure(list(playerShort = c("lucas-wilchez", "john-utaka", 
"abdon-prats", "pablo-mari", "ruben-pena", "aaron-hughes"), player = c("Lucas Wilchez", 
"John Utaka", " Abdón Prats", " Pablo Marí", " Rubén Peña", "Aaron Hughes"
), club = c("Real Zaragoza", "Montpellier HSC", "RCD Mallorca", 
"RCD Mallorca", "Real Valladolid", "Fulham FC"), leagueCountry = c("Spain", 
"France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "England"), birthday = structure(c(4990, 
4390, 8386, 8643, 7868, 3598), class = "Date"), height = c(177L, 
179L, 181L, 191L, 172L, 182L), weight = c(72L, 82L, 79L, 87L, 
70L, 71L), position = c("Attacking Midfielder", "Right Winger", 
NA, "Center Back", "Right Midfielder", "Center Back"), games = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), victories = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ties = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), defeats = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), goals = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), yellowCards = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    yellowReds = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), redCards = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), photoID = c("95212.jpg", "1663.jpg", 
    NA, NA, NA, "3868.jpg"), rater1 = c(0.25, 0.75, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.25), rater2 = c(0.5, 0.75, NA, NA, NA, 0), refNum = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), refCountry = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L
    ), Alpha_3 = c("GRC", "ZMB", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "LUX"), 
    meanIAT = c(0.326391469021736, 0.203374724564378, 0.369893594187172, 
    0.369893594187172, 0.369893594187172, 0.325185154120009), 
    nIAT = c(712L, 40L, 1785L, 1785L, 1785L, 127L), seIAT = c(0.000564112354334542, 
    0.0108748941063986, 0.000229489640866464, 0.000229489640866464, 
    0.000229489640866464, 0.00329680952361961), meanExp = c(0.396, 
    -0.204081632653061, 0.588297311544544, 0.588297311544544, 
    0.588297311544544, 0.538461538461538), nExp = c(750L, 49L, 
    1897L, 1897L, 1897L, 130L), seExp = c(0.0026964901062936, 
    0.0615044043187379, 0.00100164730649311, 0.00100164730649311, 
    0.00100164730649311, 0.013752210497518), BMI = c(22.98190175237, 
    25.5922099809619, 24.1140380330271, 23.8480304816206, 23.6614386154678, 
    21.4346093466973), position_new = c("Offense", "Offense", 
    "Goalkeeper", "Defense", "Midfield", "Defense"), rater_mean = c(0.375, 
    0.75, NA, NA, NA, 0.125), ageinyear = c(28, 30, 19, 18, 20, 
    32), ageinyears = c(28, 30, 19, 18, 20, 32)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Use the data to draw a bar plot with the following characteristics:

– The x-axis displays the league country while the y-axis displays the number of games and the number of cards

– For each country there are two bars next to each other: one for the games played and one for the cards received

`barplot <- ggplot(new_soccer_referee,aes(x=leagueCountry,y=number))`

```
barplot + 

geom_bar(fill=c("games","yellowCards")) +

geom_col(Position="dodge") +
  labels(x="leagueCountry", y="number")

ggplot
```

`

I know it is pretty messy but I am really confused how to build up the layers with ggplot and how to work out the long format, can anyone help?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can help us "look under the hood" by seeing some example data. If you run `dput(head(new_soccer_referee))` it will produce a code recipe that you can copy into the body of your question. When we run that we can work with a perfect copy of (the first 6 rows of) your data, which will make it possible to have specific suggestions that actually work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added it on now, hope not look too chaotic!

Comment: Do the following: type `dput(head(new_soccer_referee))` in your console, then press enter. Then copy the output and paste it to your question!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to first aggregate your data to compute the number of `yellowCards` and `games`  by `leagueCountry`. Afterwards you could convert to long which makes it easy to plot via `ggplot2`.

Using some fake random example data to mimic your real data:

```r
set.seed(123)

new_soccer_referee <- data.frame(
  player = sample(letters, 20),
  leagueCountry = sample(c("Spain", "France", "England", "Italy"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  yellowCards = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE),
  games = sample(1:20, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

new_soccer_referee_long <- new_soccer_referee %>% 
  group_by(leagueCountry) %>%
  summarise(across(c(yellowCards, games), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-leagueCountry, names_to = "variable", values_to = "number")

ggplot(new_soccer_referee_long, aes(leagueCountry, number, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  What does 123 mean in the set.seeds bracket?

Comment: (: `set.seed(123)` sets the seed for drawing random number. Whether you use 123 or 42 or ... is not important. Important is to set the seed. This way as it ensures that when running my code you get the same numbers and the same plot and should always be used when using random numbers to make the code reproducible.

Comment: I dont know why, the errors show "could not find function "%>%" and "ggplot", while I have installed ggplot2 and dplyr packages.

Comment: Have you run `library(dplyr)` and `library(ggplot2)` (and of course `library(tidyr)`)? Just having the packages installed is not sufficient. You also have to load them to use any function from the packages.

Comment: sure, also plyr. I think it was some system problem, I just restarted the computer now it works! thank you so much!

Comment: Great. Just one point: Be aware that using `plyr` with `dplyr` could sometimes lead to mysterious issues. At least make sure that you load plyr after dplyr. However, in general it's no longer recommended to use `plyr`.

Comment: why do you use "-" before "leagueCountry" in "pivot_longer(-leagueCountry, names_to = "variable", values_to = "number")"?

Comment: `pivot_longer` converts to long format. `-leagueCountry` means to take all columns except `leagueCountry`. Basically `pivot_longer` stacks all columns (except `leagueCountry`) on top of each other where the column names become categories of a new column `variable` while the values stored in the columns are moved to a new column `number `. Doing so makes it easy to use ggplot as we now could map the column with the categories on fill and the values on y.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_soccer_referee %>% 
  select(leagueCountry, games, yellowCards) %>% 
  group_by(leagueCountry) %>% 
  summarise(games = sum(games),
            yellowCars = sum(yellowCards)
            ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-leagueCountry) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=leagueCountry, fill=name, y=value)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]